# Does iOS store the user's gender?

Tags: ios

My settings screen has a switch for male or female.

I was wondering if iOS stores the user's gender anywhere? If it does, how do you access it?

Comment: How would it know. It never asks you at sign up?

Comment: That is fine, I didn't recall it asking, but wondered if it had any Mr / Mrs / Miss salutation from setting up your ID, and if so, if it was available!

Comment: @logixologist with facial recognition xD

Comment: @Popeye: though i feel your pain please don't be rude to users. MrNeilM here is a member for 21 days...

Comment: @rokjarc I wouldn't consider my comment rude. If they don't learn then the `xcode` tag will just be filled full of pointless unrelated questions. There are more then enough users that would join me in this and from what I have seen of how they tell users mine is pretty tamed. If you go through this users questions they are pointlessly using the `xcode` tag when it isn't needed.

Comment: @MrNeilM: Popeye has a point there - don't tag a question with Xcode if it has (almost) nothing to do with it...

Comment: @Popeye: I know: H2CO3 for example would sign your comment anytime :)

Comment: Sorry for putting xcode. I hadn't actually meant to. Agree that it has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It doesn't, and you can't. And we should all be thankful for that.

If the question is in your settings screen it is from a third-party app. Those settings, and the values stored in them, aren't available within your app.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think it did, but as I have a control, I thought it best to check, as if the information was available it would be prudent to self configure!

Comment: My settings screen doesn't, that I can see. Is this in an app-specific settings screen?

Comment: It's in app. But clearly if the data was available it would be sensible to adjust automatically!

Comment: Settings from other apps aren't available to you in iOS.

Comment: I wasn't thinking from other apps, I was thinking if Apple gathered it at any point and if so if they exposed it. But it seems they don't which is fine.

Comment: I've updated the answer to confirm. Hope it helps.